# Simple Python generator skips steps with for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, generator

Trying to understand generators, I write:

```
def counter():
    n = 1
    while n <= 10:
        yield n
        n += 1
```

If I then manually enter

```
c = counter()
```

... followed repeatedly by

```
print c.next()
```

I get 1,2,3, etc.   But if I run

```
for i in c:
    print c.next()
```

I get 2,4,6,8...  I've stared at this for too long. What am I missing, please?

Comment: If you use both `for ... in` **and** `.next()` you are iterating twice for each step - use one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.next() iterates on the generator you have just created, just the same way when you are doing

```
for i in c
```

That's why you only have pair numbers in your second approach

Just type:

```
for i in c:
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in c:
    print c.next()
```

is essentially the same as

```
c_iter = iter(c)
while True:
    try:
        i = c_iter.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print c_iter.next()
```

Your `for` loop is getting a value from the generator, then ignoring it and fetching another one to print.